# Payment Gateway actions

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I'm developing an asp.net site and want to integrate payment collection. The user buys credits and then can do some action depending on the balance. I dont want to fully integrate the payment gateeway, as this is complex. Paypal has two options Standard and Pro. I would prefer the Standard.

Two issues:

1. The user is already logged into the site. Can I use the same credentials for the payment gateway without the user typing in their details again (or at least limit) when it comes to payment section using a non-integration method?
2. After makes a pament via the payment gateway, I want the user to be able to carry out some action (as they have a balance). So If payment is made and verified then add x credits to the application. Is this possible without a fully integrated solution?

I havent yet decided on the payment provider yet, open to suggestions. Think paypal would be a good fit though.
Hope someone can assist pls?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use paypal apis for these easily. but make sure that RBI let you do it, as your name is Indian, so I guess you are doing it with a paypal account of India. before taking any step must contact paypal Support via Email / phone. 'coz on their developer site http://developer.paypal.com a lot of great apis but when you come to use 'em they don't work and when you ask for support they say RBI.... blah blah

Comment: I'm in the UK! If I use Paypal's API's will this be a Paypal Pro integration? If yes, could you explain further pls?

Comment: okay. Sorry for late reply. but you should first make it clear what you want?

  explain it - "The user buys credits and then can do some action depending on the balance." what actions? 

"1The user is already logged into the site. Can I use the same credentials for the payment gateway without the user typing in their details again"

  do you wanna use users credential of paypal i.e his paypal id/password?? or which credential you are talking about??

   And as you are in UK o.O I think you should know simple rule of thumb, Go and call paypal support or drop 'em an email! They are most helpful